# Locking Postgres Tables with Twisted Python

Tags: python, postgresql, twisted

I have a twisted daemon that does some xml feed parsing.

I store my data in PostgreSQL via twisted.enterprise.adbapi , which IIRC is wrapping psycopg2

I've run into a few problems with storing data into database -- with duplicate data periodically getting in there.

To be honest, there are some underlying issues with my implementation which should be redone and designed much better.  I lack the time and resources to do that though - so we're in 'just keep it running' mode for now.

I think the problem may happen from either my usage of deferToThread or how I've spawned the server at the start.

As a quick overview of the functionality I think is at fault:

Twisted queries Postgres for Accounts that should be analyzed , and sets a block on them

```
SELECT 
    id 
FROM 
    xml_sources 
WHERE 
    timestamp_last_process < ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' - INTERVAL '4 HOUR' ) 
    AND
    is_processing_block IS NULL ;

lock_ids = [ i['id'] for i in results ]

UPDATE xml_sources SET is_processing_block = True WHERE id IN %(lock_ids)s
```

What I think is happening, is (accidentally) having multiple servers running or various other issues results in multiple threads processing this data.

I think this would likely be fixed - or at least ruled out as an issue - if I wrap this quick section in an exclusive table lock.

I've never done table locking through twisted before though.  can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [`SELECT FOR UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) instead of a plain `SELECT`, and that will lock the rows returned by your query.  If you actually want *table* locking you can just issue a [`LOCK`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html) statement, but based on the rest of your question I think you want row locking.

If you are using `adbapi`, then keep in mind that you will need to use [`runInteraction`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool.html#runInteraction) if you want to run more than one statement in a transaction.  Functions passed to `runInteraction` will run in a thread, so you may need to use `callFromThread` or [`blockingCallFromThread`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.2.0/api/twisted.internet.threads.blockingCallFromThread.html) to reach from the database interaction back into the reactor.

However, locking may not be your problem.  For one thing, if you are mixing `deferToThread` and `adbapi`, something's likely wrong.  `adbapi` is already doing the equivalent of `deferToThread` *for* you.  You should be able to do everything on the main thread.

You'll have to include a representative example for a more specific answer though.  Consider your question: it's basically "Sometimes I get duplicate data, with a self-admittedly problematic implementation, that is big and I can't fix and I also can't show you."  This is not a question which it is possible to answer.

Comment: Thanks. 

1. I'll implement the select for update.
2. I'll read up on runInteraction

Comment: the full 'thanks' didn't go through on the comment.  Yes the question could have been better - but I would have had to reformat 200+ lines of code to convey this.  so i should do that in another question.